# How to prevent statically generated pages from being cached without opting into ISR in Next.js

Tags: javascript, caching, next.js, cdn, production

I'm trying to customize the `Cache-Control` headers with which my NextJS server responds when serving pages that were generated at build time (SSG). The rationale is simple: given that every server response is cached by the CDN according to its headers, and given that I want every static page to be refreshed as soon as I roll out a new deploy, the default caching policy (`s-maxage=31536000, stale-while-revalidate`, [source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/228640eedd2c0b001850e42b2ebfe2288e72ff0c/packages/next/server/send-payload.ts#L37)) doesn't cut it for me.

The `revalidate` [option](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#revalidate), if set to `1` (`0` throws a build error), would get very close to the intended behavior, but it would have the unfortunate side effect of regenerating the page at most once every second. As stated above, the page is strictly static, so server-rendering it 60 times a minute would only be a waste of resources.

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<
  EntityProps,
  EntityPathParams
> = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const entity = getEntity(id);
  // Activates ISR--waste of resources
  return { props: entity, revalidate: 1 };
};
```

It should be noted that the `Cache-Control` headers one sets in their `next.config.js` are very "helpfully" [overridden in production](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers#cache-control), so this is not a feasible solution.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  async headers() {
    return [
      // Overridden in production
      {
        source: '/entity/:path',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: 'public, max-age=0, must-revalidate',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

I don't see any way to customize the headers at this point. Am I mistaken? Can you point me to some additional resources? Do you know any alternative approach?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is `getServerSideProps` instead. You have full control of `Cache-Control` when using it. Alternatively, you could look into [On-demand Revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation) of your static pages.

Comment: But `getServerSideProps` would render the page at every request, wouldn't it? Given that my goal is to keep the `Cache-Control` header set to `0`, the ability to customize it wouldn't make much of a difference given that SSR doesn't cache content by default anyway.

On-demand ISR looks nice, and wasn't available at the time the question was posted. Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, even if I revalidated the page, the old content would still be available on the CDN because of the original cache directives. As long as we can't edit those (and stay static), I fear any workaround will fail

Answer (score -1):

You can't. If you are using SSG the site gets build DURING buildtime, meaning that there is no server involved at all when the user sees the site. AFTER the page gets build, you send the out folder, which contains all the assets, html and js files, to some static website hosting, like AWS S3. There, you can customize the cache headers that are sent to the browser.

Summary: SSG happens on nextjs build time, it generates HTML and then a hosting server has to serve those files.

Comment: As I specified in the question, I am using a NextJS server, not a static host, so THERE IS a server involved when the user sees the site. Whether they are prebuilt or rendered on the fly, requests for pages pass through the same runtime. The runtime is ultimately in control of the headers it sets. Unfortunately, it appears `Cache-Control` values can't be customized for statically generated pages